# How to set custom schema from helm chart for superset postgresql

Tags: apache-superset

We are using custom postgresql for superset and we are able to connect successful below connection string. But, superset by default using "public" schema. How do we set custom schema name from helm chart in superset postgresql.

`SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = f"postgresql+psycopg2://{env('DB_USER')}:{env('DB_PASS')}@{env('DB_HOST')}:{env('DB_PORT')}/{env('DB_NAME')}"`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We found the way to add search_path in database uri. It fixed our issue

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = f"postgresql+psycopg2://{env('DB_USER')}:{env('DB_PASS')}@{env('DB_HOST')}:{env('DB_PORT')}/{env('DB_NAME')}?sslmode=require&options=-csearch_path={env('DB_SCHEMA')}"